# -vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to run the following cmd, which should add a watermark and scroll text to the video

```
G:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -y -v error -i G:/hls/test3.mp4 -i G:/hls/logo.png -filter_complex overlay=x=10:y=10 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -filter:v drawtext="text='hello':x=50+n*2:y=50" G:/hls/output/test3.mp4
```

I receive the following error.

```
Filtergraph 'drawtext=text='hello':x=50+n*2:y=50' was specified through the -vf/-af/-filter option for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph.
-vf/-af/-filter and -filter_complex cannot be used together for the same stream.
```

How can I acheive both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I had read well your post, so I do now. Please try this cmd:

```
G:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe -y -v error -i G:/hls/test3.mp4 -i G:/hls/logo.png -filter_complex overlay=x=10:y=10,drawtext=fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf:fontcolor=white:fontsize=38:text='hello':x=50+n*2:y=50" -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy G:/hls/output/test3.mp4
```

This one works very well with me.

Comment: That is not a really helpful answer. What should the OP do to fix the command?

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. Please, read it again.

Comment: If the OP removes either the filter or filter_complex option, the command will not do what the OP wanted. How can these filters be combined such that command does what is intended?

Comment: I reedited my answer. Now I informed OP an useful cmd that will solve its question certainly.

Comment: Thanks for improving the answer!